# Capturing output of ping in c

Tags: c, linux, pipeline

How can I capture the output of ping command via pipeline immediately ?

Here is my code:

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *cmd = popen ( "ping -c 3 google.com | grep icmp", "r" );//ping google
    char *s = malloc ( sizeof ( char ) * 200 );
    while ( 1 )
    {
            fgets ( s, sizeof ( char )*200, cmd );
            printf ( "%s", s);//show outcome
            if ( strstr ( s, "icmp_req=3" ) != 0 )
                    break;
    }
    pclose ( cmd );
    return 0;
}
```

When the program finished, it will show the output at the same time. But I would like to read the output immediately while the program execute.

Comment: Using fork could solve your problem

Answer (score 8):

`<stdio.h>`  is buffered by default, and `stdout` is line-buffered.

Replace your `printf("%s", s);`  with `printf("%s\n", s);` (the ending newline would flush the `stdout` buffer) or add a call to `fflush(NULL);` just after it.

Actually, your question is unrelated to `ping`, but the pipe is buffered.

You might do the lower level `pipe`, `fork`, `dup2`, `read` syscalls and manage explicitly the buffer on the pipe. Then calling `poll` could be useful.

You could consider using a ICMP pinging library like [liboping](http://verplant.org/liboping/) or consider instead doing an HTTP request (either using the `wget` program, or preferably [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/); perhaps a simple HTTP `HEAD` request could be enough). As a general advice avoid forking a process with `popen` or `system` (because the commands available might not be the same on the target computer).

Read some good Linux programming book, like http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: I don't think `printf("%s\n", s);` will resolve problem! does it?

Comment: Unfortunately, printf("%s\n", s) and fflush(NULL) do not work for me.

Comment: Then, as I suggested, do the lower-level syscalls.... And use `poll` because the issue is related to buffering.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a small code that uses [liboping](http://verplant.org/liboping/) to ping www.xively.com every second and display the latency. You can install liboping static/dynamic library files and header files on your ubuntu box like so: `sudo apt-get install liboping0 liboping-dev oping`

Then compile the following program with the above library (`gcc -o test test.c -loping`). And run the executable as a super user (sudo).

**test.c:**

```
 /*
  * 1. install liboping, e.g. `sudo apt-get install liboping0 liboping-dev oping`
  * 2. Compile with -loping, e.g. `gcc -o test test.c -loping`
  * 3. Execute using sudo as super user, e.g. `sudo ./test`
  */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <oping.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pingobj_t *ping;
    pingobj_iter_t *iter;

    if ((ping = ping_construct()) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ping_construct failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("ping_construct() success\n");

    if (ping_host_add(ping, "www.xively.com") < 0) {
        const char * errmsg = ping_get_error(ping);
        fprintf(stderr, "ping_host_add(www.xively.com) failed. %s\n", errmsg);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("ping_host_add() success\n");

    while (1) {
        if (ping_send(ping) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ping_send failed\n");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("ping_send() success\n");

        for (iter = ping_iterator_get(ping); iter != NULL; iter =
                ping_iterator_next(iter)) {
            char hostname[100];
            double latency;
            unsigned int len;

            printf("ping_iterator_get() success\n");
            len = 100;
            ping_iterator_get_info(iter, PING_INFO_HOSTNAME, hostname, &len);
            len = sizeof(double);
            ping_iterator_get_info(iter, PING_INFO_LATENCY, &latency, &len);

            printf("hostname = %s, latency = %f\n", hostname, latency);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("exiting...\n");

    ping_destroy( ping );

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
anurag@anurag-PC:~$ sudo ./test
ping_construct() success
ping_host_add() success
ping_send() success
ping_iterator_get() success
hostname = www.xively.com, latency = 233.666000
ping_send() success
ping_iterator_get() success
hostname = www.xively.com, latency = 234.360000
ping_send() success
ping_iterator_get() success
hostname = www.xively.com, latency = 234.076000
ping_send() success
ping_iterator_get() success
hostname = www.xively.com, latency = 231.761000
ping_send() success
ping_iterator_get() success
hostname = www.xively.com, latency = 235.085000
^C
```

liboping is good if you want to check for internet connectivity from your linux device provided your ISP or target does not block ICMP packets. If these are blocked, you can use some HTTP library to try and fetch the index.html page from www.google.com or any other website and check if that succeeds

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read it immediatelly, and it does not print at the end of execution.

It is displayed at the moment when

- the buffer of the pipe is filled or
- the pipe closes

You need to modify the properties of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `printf("%s", s);` with `printf("%s\n", s);`

`\n` will flush your buffer so you will get output as soon as the `printf` command executed and you need not to wait until program execution stopped...

Answer (score 0):

Just force the newline output, then the `stdout` flush, changing cmd with

```
char *cmds = "ping -c 3 google.com | awk ' /icmp/ { printf(\"%s\\n\", $0); } '";
FILE *cmd = popen ( cmds, "r" );
```

It works, tested by myself.

Other methods won't work because the problem is about the pipe flushing, not the current process stdout flush.